# Decode a part of Bitmap from file in Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have a file with a very large image: for example 9000x9000.

I can't load the Bitmap in memory because the heap size. But I only need to display a small part of this bitmap for example the rect width=100-200 and height =200-400 (resulting size of the sub-bitmap =100x200)

How can I retrieve this bitmap from the file?

Note: I dont want to lose quality in the 100x200 image

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

is it possible that there is a solution for this?

for example , [BitmapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html) .

It should work for API10 and above...

Usage:

```
BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(...).decodeRegion(...)
```

Comment: apparently that would be the proper answer.

Answer (score 4):

It can easily be done using [RapidDecoder](https://github.com/suckgamony/RapidDecoder).

I actually generated a 9000x9000 png which its file size is about 80MB and the 200x400 sized region was successfully loaded.

```
import rapid.decoder.BitmapDecoder;

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapDecoder.from("big-image.png")
                             .region(145, 192, 145 + 200, 192 + 400)
                             .decode();
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

It works for Android 2.2 and above.

Comment: Wow, this sounds promising. does the whole decoding being done on JNI ? which file formats are supported? does it even support WebP ? does it include face detection?

Comment: +1 very good library,also the quality of image is 80% maintained..and works on almost all devices

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can use the BitmapFactory method that allows you to specify the Rect that you want to decode.

```
public static Bitmap decodeStream (InputStream is, Rect outPadding, BitmapFactory.Options opts)
```

Comment: The outPadding is an out put parameter

Comment: @Addev I'm really interesting.. so don't you think that is possible to take only some rect of a bitmaps before importing it? :)

Comment: in which cases do the outPadding get filled? when it's 9-patch? are there other cases? also, even if it's 9-patch, what does it mean and what would be filled?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        int inSampleSize = 1;
        if (height > reqHeight) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        }
        int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;
        if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }
        options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. Not even on a PC, I fail to see how you could do that without loading the entire image: most image formats, for example PNGs, have the pixel data zipped, so you need to at least unzip the IDAT chunk before you can start doing anything else and that will basically decode the whole image.

In your shoes I would try to have a server do it for me. Where do you get the image anyway? Not from a server? Then try to make a WS request that will give you the proper part of the image. If the image does NOT come from the server you can nevertheless send it to your server to get back only the part of the image that you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I'm trying to make is implement an MultiTouchImageView and thats for loading only the part of the image visible due to the zoom and scroll position, allowing to load big images without losing quality and without memory crashes. How can I do that?

Comment: In that case I think what you are trying to do is simply technically impossible with the limitations of a mobile device: you just can't offer the user a good experience without loading the whole image in memory and just displaying the part that you need. Even if you could load just a part of the image, you would have to do it every time the user pans or zooms a bit... since the operation would be slow, the user experience would be crappy anyway. The only way to do this is to put some upper limit on the size of the image. Otherwise you just can't do it IMHO.

Comment: Hmmm what you say is very logical but how does the Android's Gallery load those big images allowing to zoom in with the same quality?

Comment: The beauty of Android is that you can look at the source code of the apps... Including Android's Gallery one. Here's the link https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Gallery/tree/eclair/src/com/android/camera I'm looking at BaseImage.java (in the galery subdirectory) and the Util.java class (particularily the makeBitmap() methods) and it seems to me that they ARE doing scaling...  options.inSampleSize = computeSampleSize(options, minSideLength, maxNumOfPixels); [...]

Comment: This answer is outdated or just not right. There is no problem in loading sub-image of image of this size in Android API level 10.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    Bitmap b = null;
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        b=Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o), 100, 200, 200, 400, null, null);
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return b;
}
```

Am not sure, but this may give some idea to you

Comment: It gives an out of memory error because the BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o) doesn't return until the whole Bitmap is retrieved