# Drawing large image on canvas while preserving quality for zooming

Tags: android

I´m woriking on an android project and want to create an interactive worldmap.
**Desired result**: Beeing able to zoom in and out on a map and the ability to "swipe to move". The map will be just one image, posibly set as a background, or drawn first on a canvas. On the map peoples locations will be drawn (The app will keep track of people in games, movies, books), so the peoples locations will often change and the picture redrawn. The result will then be displayed.
My first problem is when I try to load my image and draw it on my canvas. My image is about 5000x5000 pixels, and i get

```
06-25 10:40:28.053: E/AndroidRuntime(1217): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

I have read [Decode a part of Bitmap from file in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651881/decode-a-part-of-bitmap-from-file-in-android) hoping that something like that would be a solution, but when reading the responses it didn´t seem to work...
Q1: Is there any way to load a big image, draw on it, and then display the result in android?
Q2: If so, how?
Q3: If this doesn´t work, or is just to hard, can you recomend an alternative?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The project was canceled due to other reasons. I haven't looked at this for a long time. Hopefully Android has been updated to better handle large images, or in a convenient way increase the VM budget.